# Angular2 life cycle methods execute out of order

Tags: sockets, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using Angular2 with `ionic`, and I have this sort of component:

```
class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("init");
        socket.on("something", this.something.bind(this));
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        console.log("destroy");
        socket.remove("something", this.something.bind(this));
    }
}
```

To open this page, I write `this.nav.setRoot(MyComponent)`. Now my page is showing `MyComponent`, and the socket is listening for "something".

To refresh it, I write `this.nav.setRoot(MyComponent)` again. Now my page is showing `MyComponet`, and the socket is not listening for "something".

The console output is:

> init
>
> init
>
> destroy

---

- Why is it first run `ngOnInit` of the second component, and only then `ngOnDestroy` of the first one?
- Is there a way to first call the destroy, and then the init?
- Is there another way I should handle my socket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparentally, ionic has it's own lifecycle functions, as mentioned [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/).

- Instead of `ngOnInit` use `ionViewDidLoad`
- Instead of `ngOnDestoy` use `ionViewWillLeave`

Works like magic.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand this, you cannot really control, what should happen first in between `ngOnInit` of the **second component** and `ngOnDestroy` of the **first one**. These hooks, from 2 different components, at least, are not dependent on each other. Whether hooks on the same component are dependent on each other. Read [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html).

May be, this depends on whatever gets triggered faster at the moment.

In this case, what you can do is, you can move your code from `ngOnDestroy` before calling `this.nav.setRoot(MyComponent)`.

Also, if the requirement does not suite this kind of code, you can try to refresh a particular type of UI component which needs to be refreshed than refreshing the entire component like `this.nav.setRoot(MyComponent)`.

You can refresh a particular UI component using DOM using `document.getElementByID('myDiv')` type of operations.

Hope this helps. If not, please mention the specifics.